# Sound not working after ending HDMI connection

Tags: sound, 13.10, hp, hdmi

I have an HP Envy 15t-j000 installed with Ubuntu 13.10. When connecting my computer to a monitor via HDMI, I have no problem getting the sound to come from the monitor speakers. My problem is that after disconnecting the HDMI cable, my computer's speakers don't produce any sound from YouTube, VLC, Spotify, and etc. What's odd though is that system sounds are still there, such as the sounds you get when pushing on the increase or decrease volume buttons. Also, the sound test in sound settings works perfectly. Any solutions? Could it just be a bug because this is a new release?

Comment: Please test if the issue persists when we close the application streaming audio **before** we unplug the HDMI device.

Comment: This bug is still present in 18.04. I need to plug hdmi cable again, select internal audio speaker in sound settings and unplug cable to fix this.

Answer (score 7):

[PulseAudio Volume Control](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pavucontrol) lets you set the output device of each app that's currently playing sound.  It seems like the default sound settings dialog should have this functionality, but currently it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The solution i found is changing the profile hardware to "Stéréo analogique Output" in Audio hardware setup (click on mixer -> mixer -> settings -> audio setup). It seems that when connecting an external monitor, ubuntu automatically changes the audio hardware to HDMI output.

Comment: what is mixer ?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. For me the following worked:

1. Go to System settings
2. Sound
3. Sound effects card
4. If alert volume is on 0 or muted, unmute it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in 18.04. Restarting PulseAudio worked for me.

pulseaudio -k    ( stops PulseAudio)

pulseaudio -D    ( restarts PulseAudio as daemon, maybe not necessary since PulseAudio restarts itself )

Answer (score 0):

Search for pulseaudio in Applications.
Pulseaudio Volume Control:
Click Output Devices: Check that Speakers are chosen as ouput device.
Click Playback: Check that Built in audio is not set to HDMI.